# How can I validate any of my work on Hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, oozie

I am currently working on an issue to solve the problem of Oozie Coordinator which pools NameNode for Data check. As a case study I came to know that Yahoo runs more than 15000 jobs on a daily basis. So if most of jobs are Data Dependent It will be an overhead on NameNode. I am currently working on a cluster which has 3-4 Nodes, basically our own laptops. But my prof has asked me how can I validate my work on such a large scale. I have to provide him some analysis to prove that my solution will work on that scale. Please suggest me some options for doing the same?

Answer (score 1):

The Hadoop cluster can be simulated using [Mumak](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/contrib/mumak/). The code for Mumak is [there](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-0.21/mapreduce/src/contrib/mumak/) in the 0.21 release and not there in the trunk. It's a contrib module, so there had not been much of active work or documentation around Mumak. Here is the [JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MAPREDUCE-728) for the same. Also, take a look at [Ankus](http://mist.cs.wayne.edu/Ankus.html) project, it has reference to [mrsim](http://code.google.com/p/mrsim/) and [mrperf](http://research.cs.vt.edu/dssl/mrperf/).

This is an area which is not focused much as of now. But, would be a nice topic for someone to do some research and get some code out.